# How to use the CalendarChange function in loop statement

Tags: date-and-time

I tried to use the following loops, but without sucess:

```
For[i = 1, i < 7, i++,
 data = {632, 1, i};
 CalendarChange[data, Gregorian, Islamic]
 ]
```

and

```
For[i = 1, i <= 20, i++, CalendarChange[{632, 1, i}, Gregorian, Islamic]]
```

Comment: To format code on this website, highlight it and select the `{}` button.

Comment: Try this code: `Table[CalendarChange[{632, 1, i}, Gregorian, Islamic], {i, 20}]`

Comment: Thank you. This also did not work, here is what I got:

{CalendarChang‌​e[{632, 1, 1}, Gregorian, Islamic], 
 CalendarChang‌​e[{632, 1, 2}, Gregorian, Islamic], 
 CalendarChang‌​e[{632, 1, 3}, Gregorian, Islamic], 
 CalendarChang‌​e[{632, 1, 4}, Gregorian, Islamic], 
 CalendarChang‌​e[{632, 1, 5}, Gregorian, Islamic], 
 CalendarChang‌​e[{632, 1, 6}, Gregorian, Islamic], 
 CalendarChang‌​e[{632, 1, 7}, Gregorian, Islamic], 
 CalendarChang‌​e[{632, 1, 8}, Gregorian, Islamic], 
 ....

Comment: Have you run `Needs["Calendar`"]`?

Comment: Hello Feyre, Thank you for your help. 
Yes, I did run the Needs [Calendar"]' function, but got the same results. After calling the help desk of Mathematica, I was informed that the CalendarChange function has been superseded by the function CalenderConvert function. Using the new function solved the problem.